# Appending a StringBuilder to another StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I've written some code which has a lot of string creation. To try to avoid the expensive string creation over and over, I'm using the java `StringBuilder` class.

My code is a bit like this:

```
public String createString(){
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  for(int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE ; i++){ //its not actually this, but it's a large loop. 
      stringBuilder.append(appendString())
  }
  return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

The `appendString` method also instantiates a `StringBuilder` and appends to it.

To save time, I noticed that I could make my `appendString` method return a `StringBuilder`, rather than a `String` which avoids returning the stringBuilder using the `.toString()` method like so:

```
public StringBuilder appendString(){
  StringBuilder appendBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  appendBuilder.append("whatever");
  return appendBuilder;
}
```

This is all fine until I looked at the `StringBuilder` documentation and realised that there is no `append(StringBuilder stringBuilder)` method on the `StringBuilder` class, only an `append(String string)`.

So my question is, how does this code run? Is it casting `StringBuilder` to `String` anyway?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`StringBuilder` has a `public StringBuilder append(CharSequence s)` method. `StringBuilder` implements the `CharSequence` interface, so you can pass a `StringBuilder` to that method.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of `append()` overloads, including `append(CharSequence cs)`. Strings are handled in their own method, other `CharSequences` not having their own overload are handled by the more general one.

Interestingly there **is** an `append(StringBuffer sb)`.